# My .tex file was replaced by a blank file

Tags: mactex, texworks

I was writing a document with latex using Texworks, suddenly it stopped working. I forced the Texworks to terminate and started again, still the same. Finally I have restarted my computer and then tried again. This time .tex file is empty, all the contents have gone . Is there a way to recover my file?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX!  Were you actively working with your file?  That is to say, did you compile it at all?

Comment: I know this doesn't help and it's not what you want to hear but: you really want to backup important stuff and better yet, *additionally* put important projects into a version control system right from the beginning. Frequent checkins. Or use Sparkleshare, then you won't have to care about checkins at all (but there might be performance problems in an active TeX directory).

Comment: @Sean yes. @ christian ok but now iave to submit my thesis in a week. I really need help

Comment: Then your file should still exist, unless your entire computer threw up on it.  What does the file system explorer tell you as for its size?

Comment: @Sean only 1 KB

Comment: I don't have much grounds to say this, but I fear there is little that can be done.  TeXWorks seems to have [a history](http://timothyandrewbarber.blogspot.com/2011/02/more-on-latex-editors-texworks-texmaker.html) of fuddling up files.  I would direct this question to Unix.SE as opposed to here; unless one of the developers of TeXWorks chimes in, this has little to do with our common areas of expertise.  :-(